# Retrieving a single line from a html table from another website?

Tags: php, html, curl, xhtml, xampp

I am try to learn curl usage, but I do not understand how it works fully yet. How can I use curl (or other functions) to access on one (the top) data entry of a table. So far I am only able to retrieve the entire website. How can I only echo the whole table and specifically the first entry. My code is:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using curl is a good start, but its not going to be enough, as hanky suggested, you need to also use `DOMDocument` and also you can include `DOMXpath`.

Sample Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = curl_exec($ch); // the whole document (in string) goes in here
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); // load it
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// point it to the particular table
// table with a class named 'reference', second row (first data), get the td
$table_row = $xpath->query('//table[@class="reference"]/tr[2]/td');
foreach($table_row as $td) {
    echo $td->nodeValue . ' ';
}
```

Should output:

```
Jill Smith 50
```

Comment: How do I echo it in the same format, meaning, Jill would be to the left, Smith in the middle and 50 on the right of the same row?

Comment: @user3517904 oh okay, just omit `<br/>`, or replace it with `' '` (space)